# jquery fade in/out in same space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a site where I have a tabbed area (three tabs) which when hovered on, fade in different height divs.
The page loads with the divs hidden and are only to fade in the corresponding div when the link is hovered on.  If any div is already shown, it should fade out (or ideally appear to fade into the next div).
I've already formed two methods but they have messy results, especially when dragging the mouse randomly across the links; too many divs appear and animations run before others finish.
Any ideas on how I can make this work would be greatly appreciated; so what's there is replaced with the next div.
Here's whats failed so far:
**Version 1**

```
$(function () {
    $('#one-box').hide();
    $('#two-box').hide();
    $('#three-box').hide();

    // Box one
    $('#one-link').hover(function () {
        $('#two-box').fadeOut(300);
        $('#three-box').fadeOut(300);
        $('#one-box').delay(400).fadeIn(300);
    });
    // Box two
    $('#two-link').hover(function () {
        $('#one-box').fadeOut(300);
        $('#three-box').fadeOut(300);
        $('#two-box').delay(400).fadeIn(300);
    });
    // Box three
    $('#three-link').hover(function () {
        $('#one-box').fadeOut(300);
        $('#two-box').fadeOut(300);
        $('#three-box').delay(400).fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

**Version 2**

```
$(function () {

    $('#one-box').hide();
    $('#two-box').hide();
    $('#three-box').hide();

    // Box one
    $('#one-link').hover(function () {
        $('#two-box').animate({
            opacity: 'toggle',
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 'slow', function () {
            $('#three-box').animate({
                opacity: 'toggle',
                height: 'toggle'
            }, 'slow', function () {
                $('#one-box').animate({
                    opacity: 'toggle',
                    height: 'toggle'
                }, 'slow');
            });
        });
    });

    // Box two
    $('#two-link').hover(function () {
        $('#one-box').animate({
            opacity: 'toggle',
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 'slow', function () {
            $('#three-box').animate({
                opacity: 'toggle',
                height: 'toggle'
            }, 'slow', function () {
                $('#two-box').animate({
                    opacity: 'toggle',
                    height: 'toggle'
                }, 'slow');
            });
        });
    });

    // Box three
    $('#three-link').hover(function () {
        $('#one-box').animate({
            opacity: 'toggle',
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 'slow', function () {
            $('two-box').animate({
                opacity: 'toggle',
                height: 'toggle'
            }, 'slow', function () {
                $('#three-box').animate({
                    opacity: 'toggle',
                    height: 'toggle'
                }, 'slow');
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: How is it failing? Is the fadeIn working the first time and failing after the first time? Can you describe exactly how your code is failing?

Comment: Also, if you use Firebug on FF or Inspect Element (right click) on Google Chrome, do any error messages display?

Comment: Sorry, wrong phrasing used... it isn't the code failing its it's aesthetics failing as in that sometimes when wiping the mouse across the links (shifting the pointer across the screen), some animations haven't finished before the next begin.  Therefore its possible to get all three div boxes showing one below each other as the fades are running from one link whilst running from the other.  I think it needs a stop or to check if any animations are running before proceeding but couldn't work out how. I also read some things about fadeTo but not sure if that's right either.

Answer (score 0):

Try decreasing your fadeOut time:

```
$('#one-link').hover(function () {
    $('#two-box').fadeOut(100);//100 ms as an example
    $('#three-box').fadeOut(100);
    $('#one-box').delay(400).fadeIn(300);
});
```

or you can try as a crude solution:

```
$('#one-link').hover(function () {
    $('#two-box, #three-box').fadeOut(300, function() {
        $('#one-box').fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... I've tried changing the timings (the first method you've suggested) and have changed to sliding rather than fades as looks better when dealing with boxes of different heigh but I still get the same problem no matter how I change the times, rubbing across the links can build up a stack of div's... how can I wait for (or stop) any animations before proceeding?

Comment: The second method does work a lot nicer than the first but I still get the problem when duplicating the method for showing the second and third box: when dragging a mouse across the links quickly it's possible to make all the boxes appear.

Comment: OK...did you try decreasing the fadeOut time for the second method to a smaller number...perhaps 100 ms

Comment: Still the same problem... when hovering across the links it's possible to make the divs all appear: `$('#one-link').hover(function () {
        $('#two-box,#three-box').slideUp(100, function () {
            $('#one-box').slideDown();
        });
    });

    $('#two-link').hover(function () {
        $('#one-box,#three-box').slideUp(100, function () {
            $('#two-box').slideDown();
        });
    });`

Comment: So they never fadeOut or are they all present on the screen at the same time for a brief period of time? It might not be possible to use fadeOut for what you're trying to do....another option is to use display:none for the divs you want to disappear....you will only have the fadeIn option though.

Comment: When using the site purposefully, it does work as expected. However, if rolling across the links (hovers) at speed as one might when moving a cursor around the screen it fades (or slides) the divs in but doesn't get rid of what's already there... I was wondering if there's a way to check that all animation has stopped (or stop all animation) before starting the function?

Comment: I fixed it!  Many, many thanks! Added `$(other_divs).stop(true,true);` before the slideup part and it all seems good!  Thank you so much for getting here! :-)